# model a periodic time-varing real variable in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

What I want to model is a periodic time-varing real variable, the following code can not be simulated. Does somebody have suggestion?

```
class try
discrete Real x(start = 1);
algorithm
when sample(0,4) then 
   x :=  1; // reinit(x, 1) also does not work
end when;
equation
      der(x) = 1;
end try;
```

All the error message is listed as follows:
Translation 18:32:29        0:0-0:0 Internal error Transformation Module failed!
Translation 18:32:29        0:0-0:0 Internal error BackendDAETransform.reduceIndexDummyDer failed!
Translation 18:32:29        0:0-0:0 Internal error BackendDAETransform.selectDummyState: no state to select
Symbolic    18:32:29        10:3-10:13  Model is structurally singular, error found sorting equations 0.0 = 1.0;
 for variables

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if you want the variable x to be continue between the sampling time istants you have to remove the *discrete* keyword, this will work fine:

```
class try
 Real x(start = 1);
algorithm 
when sample(0,4) then
   reinit(x, 1);
end when;
equation 
      der(x) = 1;
end try;
```

Ciao,
Marco

Comment: But the result is still not what I want. x is not reinitialized as 1 every 4 seconds. It behaves as `der(x) = 1` without any event interrupting.

Comment: Odd, I tried Marco's version with Wolfram's SystemModeler (which uses OpenModelica behinds the scenes, as far as I know) and it worked fine.  Marco's version looks fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: Really odd, I tried it with Open Modelica and I think we found a bug, because the version I wrote before behaves as the algorithm section did not exist, but if you move the when statement under the equation section it works fine:
<pre>
model try
  Real x(start = 1);
equation
  when sample(0, 4) then
      reinit(x, 1);
  end when;
  der(x) = 1;
end try;
</pre>

Comment: Really really odd. Marco's newest version works now. I thought it was both OK to put the `when` statements in either algorithm section or equation section. BTW, Do you know how to get the dump file of OpenModelica?